# GAE/J - Moving to Cloud SDK - DataNucleus V1 Support

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

GAE/J team decided to retire App.cfg and asked everyone to move to Cloud SDK (based Maven or Gradle).
We have been using GAE/J for eight years, and we are using DataNucleus V1.

The reason that we still use DataNucleus V1 is that you can not upgrade to V2 or v3 without losing your information since they are not backward compatible (one to many relationships are not working after upgrade).

From some reason, we can not make DataNucleus V1 work with GAE/J Cloud SDK. Do you know if GAE/J stopped supporting this version? (and only support V2/V3?)

**Update**

The Ant task enhance-classes is working well if I am using GAE tools jar from version 1.9.6.3, when pointing to the current GAE tools jar (version 1.9.8.0) it fails enhacing classes.

Comment: It's hard to answer without showing error or yaml file, however I found google doc (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/jdo/overview) that is still mentioning DataNucleus V1 so it seems that this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently GAE cloud sdk appengine-java version 1.9.8.0 did not include the following libraries:

google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\lib\opt\tools->
**datanucleus\v1(few jars files)**
and
**datanucleus\v2(few jars files)**

The enhancer is looking for these jars in these directory structure which is missing.
Once you add these files and directories it is working well.

I also reported Google cloud team

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160624330

**Update**

After a few days that the issue I opened was confirmed as a "bug" and was assigned, someone decided that the bug is actually "Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)". If someone feels like me that this is a critical issue, please update your thoughts via the issue tracker link.